# Assembly MASM string comparison

Tags: assembly, masm

Im preparing for assembly language exam and im doing examples given by our teacher. Sadly i encountered a problem i dont understand. My task is to write a short assembly program where: There are two strings consist of only small letters of latin alphabet, coded in ASCII as two byte strings placed in memory. Both strings are ended with byte with value 0, and location of strings are registers ESI and EDI. Compare both strings and set the flags CF and ZF in the given manner:

CF=0 and ZF=0 if ESI string should be placed before EDI string in dictionary

CF=0 and ZF=1 if ESI string should be placed after EDI string in dictionary

CF=0 and ZF=1 if both strings are identical

In my code it works fine until i give identical strings. I dont know why, but when i give the same strings, program says that my strings are not identical. I have tried debugging so i know it happens when i compare third elements of those strings, but i dont get why it is assuming they are different, because they are the same. My conditions seems to work fine cause if i write cmp [esi+counter] and [esi+counter] it works and outputs number 3, but for cmp [esi+counter] and [edi+counter] it says they are different (in my case outputs number 1).I have no idea where is the problem. Can someone explain me what is going on? I have to work with MASM. Im using VS17 and program is 32bit.

Here is my code:

```
.686
.model flat
public _main
extern _ExitProcess@4 : PROC
extern _MessageBoxA@16 : PROC 
.data
window_title db 'Example 42', 0
string1 db 'bies', 0
size1 = $ - string1
string2 db 'bies', 0
size2 = $ - string2
output db 80 dup(?), 0 ; variable to output result
.code
_main PROC
    mov esi, OFFSET string1
    mov edi, OFFSET string2
    mov al, OFFSET size1
    mov dl, OFFSET size2
    xor ebx, ebx ; set ebx = 0
    cmp al, dl ; compare sizes i want shorter to be counter for comparsion loop
    jbe second_as_counter ; case when bl is shorter - bl is counter
    movzx ecx, al 
    jmp compare

second_as_counter:
    movzx ecx, dl

compare:
    cmp ecx, ebx ; im checking if strings are the same size, ebx starts as 0
    je same ; if none of the others condition were fullfilled it means all the letter were the same
    push ecx ; remember the counter value, cause i have no more free registers
    mov ecx, dword ptr [edi+ebx] ; compare x element of both strings
    cmp dword ptr [esi+ebx], ecx
    ja after ; if letter in esi is bigger than letter in edi, it will be placed after edi in dictionary
    jb before ; else  edi is first 
    pop ecx ; return ecx previous value
    inc ebx ; increment counter, to check next elemnt of string
    jmp compare

after:
    stc ; set carry flag
    mov ecx, 2
    dec ecx ; clear zero flag
    mov byte ptr output, byte ptr '1' ; just an output to have a proof it works
    jmp koniec

before:
    clc ; clear carry flag
    mov ecx, 2
    dec ecx ; clear zero flag
    mov byte ptr output, byte ptr '2'
    jmp koniec

same:
    cmp al, dl ; check if lenghts are the same
    je identical 
    ja after
    jmp before

identical:
    clc ; clear carry flag 
    mov ecx, 1
    dec ecx ; set zero flag
    mov byte ptr output, byte ptr '3'


koniec:
    push 0; MB_OK
    push OFFSET window_title
    push OFFSET output 
    push 0
    call _MessageBoxA@16 
    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4 
_main ENDP
END
; 1 - after(CF=1, ZF=0), 2 - before(CF=0, ZF=0), 3 - identical(CF=0, ZF=1)
```

EDIT: Ive added some commentary

Comment: You are comparing dwords not bytes, for some reason. Also your code is hard to understand, you should comment it and describe your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> CF=0 and ZF=0 if ESI string should be placed before EDI string in dictionary
>
> CF=0 and ZF=1 if ESI string should be placed after EDI string in dictionary
>
> CF=0 and ZF=1 if both strings are identical

This is not equivalent to what you mention on the last line in the program!

```
; 1 - after(CF=1, ZF=0), 2 - before(CF=0, ZF=0), 3 - identical(CF=0, ZF=1)
```

Let's assume the line from the program is correct. Anyway that's the more logical flag setting that one would expect from this kind of operation.
Code like in next snippet will set all the requested flags automatically. No need for all that hocus pocus with `STC`, `CLC`, `MOV ECX, 2` `DEC ECX`.

```
mov al, [edi + ebx]
cmp al, [esi + ebx]
ja  before            ;CF=0 ZF=0
jb  after             ;CF=1 ZF=0
; On equal you continu the loop that compares characters
; if any are left...
```

Do note that when dealing with the characters of a string, you're processing **bytes**, not **dwords** like you wrote.

---

> ```
> cmp al, dl ; compare sizes i want shorter to be counter for comparsion loop
> jbe second_as_counter ; case when bl is shorter - bl is counter
> movzx ecx, al 
> jmp compare
> second_as_counter:
> movzx ecx, dl
> compare:
> ```

You are not taking the length of the shortest string for your counter! You're doing the opposite. The `jbe` is taken when `AL` is below or equal to `DL`, meaning you should put `AL` into `ECX`.
This is my version of setting the counter:

```
    movzx   ecx, al  ; Optimistically considering 1st text to be shortest
    cmp     al, dl
    jbe     compare  ; Correct hunch
    movzx   ecx, dl  ; So who's perfect?
compare:
```

---

> ```
> push ecx
> mov  ecx, dword ptr [edi+ebx]
> cmp  dword ptr [esi+ebx], ecx
> ja   after
> jb   before
> pop  ecx
> ```

In the above snippet you should place the `pop ecx` just above the lines that branch out. That way you keep the stack balanced. In this simple program it would go by un-noticed, but in later programs this kind of error will give you many worries.

```
push ecx
mov  ecx, dword ptr [edi+ebx]
cmp  dword ptr [esi+ebx], ecx
pop  ecx                       ; Keep a balanced stack
ja   after
jb   before
```

---

> ```
> string1 db 'bies', 0
> size1 = $ - string1
> string2 db 'bies', 0
> size2 = $ - string2
> ```

With these definitions you include the zero-terminator in the length. Your code doesn't need this. Better write:

```
string1 db 'bies', 0
size1 = $ - string1 - 1
string2 db 'bies', 0
size2 = $ - string2 - 1
```

---

> ```
> push ecx ; remember the counter value, cause **i have no more free registers**
> ```

If you put the length of the 1st string in `DL` and the length of the 2nd string in `DH`, you would have `AL` to store each character from the string.